# Difference between bind and on in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, bind, underscore.js, event-binding

What is the difference between bind() and on() methods in Backbone.js

Documentation for on() : [On method documentation at backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on)

Documentation for bind() : [Bind method documentation at underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#bind)

Which of the two should be used to bind custom events for objects ?

Usage example:

```
this.bind('myEvent', this.render, this);
this.on('myEvent', this.render, this);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
this.bind('myEvent', this.render, this);
this.on('myEvent', this.render, this);
```

These are exactly equivalent and are not related to the underscore `bind` function.

Here is some code from [Backbone source](http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js):

```
// Aliases for backwards compatibility.
Events.bind   = Events.on;
Events.unbind = Events.off;
```

So, in both lines of your code, you are calling the same function.

Answer (score 3):

_.bind in underscore has nothing to do with bind in Backbone event object. ( or underscore )

_.bind in underscore is used when you want to bind a function to a context ( wrap it in a closure ). So when the function is called the context (this ) doesnt change .

the Backbone documentation explicitly says the bind method in the event is an alias to the on method. So why do you link to the bind definition in underscore ?

http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on